# swap 'display none' for fadeOut

Tags: javascript, css

How do I modify this so that it fades out and removes itself?

```
<script>
 close = document.getElementById("close");
 close.addEventListener('click', function() {
   preloader = document.getElementById("preloader");
   preloader.style.display = 'none';     <--- this part, obviously
 }, false);
</script>
```

On click "display:none" feels too jarring/unsmooth. Thanks!

Comment: easiest way would be to use jQuery. if not, you would need to make a function that changes the opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what browsers you'll need to support, you could use css-transitions to do that:

```
.fadeOut{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
```

Just add the `.fadeOut` - class to an element, for further information on transitions, see the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions). A list of compatible browsers can be seen at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=css-transitions)

Other than that, libraries like jQuery have built-in fadeIn/fadeOut - effects, which are just implemented using JavaScript and are compatible for all major browsers out there. ([jQuery APi -> fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/))

If you would prefer to do this without jQuery, you can check out how they implemented it directly in the source-code. [jsapi.info](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.0/jQuery.fn.fadeOut) is a nice code-browser, which links used internal functions, giving you the opportunity to quickly see what's getting called and how the called function looks like.

Edit:

Additionally, I just stumbled over a question on Codereview.SE that could help you out: [Fade In Fade Out in pure JavaScript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/fade-in-and-fade-out-in-pure-javascript)